# Spring - Can't get same validation error structure on 2 fields

Tags: java, spring, spring-validator

-- First of all excuse me if my english isn't perfect ;) --

I'm trying to use Custom Validator with Spring to get this structure :

```
{
    "violations": [
        {
            "fieldName": "name",
            "className": "User",
            "message": "already exists"
        }
    ],
    "type": "https://zalando.github.io/problem/constraint-violation",
    "status": 400,
    "title": "API Constraint Violation"
}
```

So I copied some class to get the new structure :

```
@API(status = STABLE)
@Immutable
public class ApiViolation {

    private final String fieldName;
    private final String className;
    private final String message;

    public ApiViolation(String fieldName, String className, String message) {
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
        this.className = className;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getFieldName() {
        return fieldName;
    }

    public String getClassName() {
        return className;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

And my User class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@JsonFilter("JsonFieldSecurityFilter")
@Audited
@Indexed
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@SearchFields({"_global"})
@UniqueUserNameConstraint
public class User extends Instanciable implements Serializable {

    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Fields({
            @Field,
            @Field(name = "_global")
    })
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(max = 256)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Club club;
```

The fact is :
1/ names can't be the same in the same club but can be the same in differents.

So when I try to get an error on the club field I get a good error :

```
Field error in object 'User' on field 'club': 
rejected value [null]; 
codes [NotNull.User.club,NotNull.club,NotNull.com.club.api.domain.Club,NotNull]; arguments [
    org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: 
        codes [User.club,club]; 
        arguments []; 
        default message [club]
]; 
default message [must not be null]
```

And when I try with a bad name it gives me :

```
Error in object 'User': 
    codes [UniqueNameInClub.User,UniqueNameInClub]; 
    arguments [
        org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: 
            codes [User.,]; 
            arguments []; 
            default message []
    ]; 
    default message [must be unique]
```

So much data is missing... Do you have an idea ?

Thank you so much !

Etienne

Comment: I'm not sure I can connect all the dots or what additional data you're expecting but since `@UniqueUserNameConstraint` is a class-level annotation (whereas `@NotNull` is on the field `club`) this seems to be correct.

Comment: Why copy classes? Just use the zalando extension, configure it and use it.

Comment: I copied classes in order to get a structure which match with what I need. Zalando gives me the Class with the field attribute & the message. Isn't it the good way to get one field more ?

Comment: @Thomas do you think that I can get the field name which trigger my error with an Entity Annotation ?

Comment: Probably yes but since I don't know the validators you're using I can't tell.

Comment: I'm using the Zalando Problem and a Custom Violation entity based on the doc I've found : https://www.baeldung.com/problem-spring-web for example